# converting matlab code to cloud service

Tags: matlab, cloud, azure-cloud-services, hp-cloud-services

I have written Matlab code( musclualr software package), frequently l have seen move application to the cloud service, and now l want to learn cloud computing, l start with my application, but l want to know the aims of converting matlab code to cloud service?

Comment: Not sure I understand, are you asking for the benefits of migrating a platform to the cloud?

Comment: @MartynC     yes actually

Comment: That all depends on the scenario really, hard to say what the benefits are in your scenario without any more context or details.

Comment: @MartynC thank you so much.

Comment: If you let us know more on your scenario then we may be able to help you.

Answer (score 4):

I know that this an old question. Since there could be anyone else looking for answers I will state it here.

I believe what you are trying to achieve is migrating your current matlab application to cloud service.

There are 2 ways that you can do this.

**Using Matlab compiler** - Matlab compiler lets you create DLL , jar depending on your language. Currently it supports .Net , Java , C/C++ , python etc.However there are limitations for this. As of you can't 100% guarantee that you will be able to rewrite youre entire codebase. and also matlab offers better solution for this scenario.(stated below)

**Using Matlab production server** - If you are looking to develop web application using your matlab code this is your ultimate solution I believe. matlab production server works like a REST service. you can host your matlab files(.m) inside the production server.
What happens here is matlab compiles your code using matlab compiler and deploy it in their cloud. afterwards you can consume this like a api through their sdk however.

**https://in.mathworks.com/help/mps/qs/create-a-deployable-archive-for-matlab-production-server.html**

I have attached the  link here incase if anyone is interested.